# SslStream.DataAvailable not a valid function

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, msdn

I am migrating C# code from using a NetworkStream to SSLStream, however where I use stream.DataAvailable I get the error:

> Error 1   'System.Net.Security.SslStream'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'DataAvailable' and no extension
>   method 'DataAvailable' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Net.Security.SslStream' could
>   be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

now my local MSDN copy does not include DataAvailable as a member of SslStream however http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170317.aspx says it does have the member DataAvailable.
here is a copy of my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

namespace Node
{

  public static class SSLCommunicator
  {
    static TcpClient client = null;
    static SslStream stream = null;
    static List<byte> networkStreamInput = new List<byte>();
    public static void connect(string server, Int32 port)
    {
        try
        {
          client = new TcpClient(server, port);
          stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(),false);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public static List<DataBlock> getServerInput() 
    {
      List<DataBlock> ret = new List<DataBlock>();
      try
      {
      //check to see if stream is readable.
      if (stream.CanRead)
      {
        //Check to see if there is data available.
        if (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
          int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
          //while data is available buffer the data.
          do
          {
            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            byte[] tmp = new byte[numberOfBytesRead];
            Array.Copy(readBuffer, tmp, numberOfBytesRead);
            networkStreamInput.AddRange(tmp);
          } while (stream.DataAvailable);
     ...
```

Also if you have a better way to get my output of the stream in to a managed array (there will be some parsing done on it later in the code) I would love the help. I am using Visual Studio 2008

--EDIT
I just realized I linked to the embedded SDK, this is not a embedded system, so how do I see if data is available in the normal .net SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are looking at is for the .NET Micro Framework.

According to [this page for .Net 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream_properties(VS.80).aspx) and [this page for .Net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream_properties.aspx), there is no DataAvailable property on SSLStream.

Edit:  Can't you just call Read() and see if you get anything back? i don't think this will block.

Comment: Nope: it ruins everything.  See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4c3d019-aecd-4fc6-9dea-680f04faa900/sslstreamread-returns-invalid-data

Comment: You can NOT call just the `Read` method, because **it will block the execution flow**. For other stream classes it is all right to call it. However It is necessary to check the `DataAvailable` property when using `NetworkStream` or `SSLStream`.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási - This is a REALLY old question, and at the time, the problem was that the OP could NOT check DataAvailable.